# How do I outline the bars of my barchart with a thick black outline?

Tags: javascript, echarts

I am new to coding and am trying to make a barchart with eCharts. I have made a simple bar chart example but now I want to make a thick outline for the bars on the chart. This is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.3.0/echarts-en.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // based on prepared DOM, initialize echarts instance
        var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

        // specify chart configuration item and data
        var option = {
            title: {
                text: 'ECharts entry example'
            },
            tooltip: {},
            legend: {
                data:['Sales']
            },
            xAxis: {
                data: ["shirt","cardign","chiffon shirt","pants","heels","socks"]
            },
            yAxis: {},
            series: [{
                name: 'Sales',
                type: 'bar',
                data: [5, 20, 36, 10, 10, 20],
            }]
        };

        // use configuration item and data specified to show chart
        myChart.setOption(option);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I add a thick black outline on the bars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the option [barBorderColor](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.itemStyle.barBorderColor) and [barBorderWidth](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.itemStyle.barBorderWidth) to set the color and width of the border respectively for each bar.
Below is an example based on your existing code.

```js
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

// specify chart configuration item and data
var option = {
  title: {
    text: 'ECharts entry example'
  },
  tooltip: {},
  legend: {
    data: ['Sales']
  },
  xAxis: {
    data: ["shirt", "cardign", "chiffon shirt", "pants", "heels", "socks"]
  },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [{
    name: 'Sales',
    type: 'bar',
    data: [5, 20, 36, 10, 10, 20],
    //Added item style
    itemStyle: {
      normal: {
        barBorderWidth: 5,
        barBorderColor: "#000"
      }
    }
  }]
};

// use configuration item and data specified to show chart
myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/4.3.0/echarts-en.min.js"></script>
<div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
```